# git submodule clone on windows not creating target folders

Tags: git, git-submodules

At work we've set up a repo appdevx and it has a project with submodules. When I run this command on OSX (`git --version` -> `git version 2.8.1`) everything works as expected, all my directories are populated, life is grand.

```
git clone --recursive ssh://git@bb/appdevx/orb.git x
```

When I run the same command on Windows in git bash (`git --version` -> `git version 2.9.0.windows.1`) it seems to download all the modules as expected and puts them in the .git folder (I didn't confirm this, but it's got a long stream of found submodules and etc) and then it goes to write to the first folder alphabetically (which for some reason isn't created on the initial clone) and fails because it can't find the target path. If I create the path (paying attention to casing) it deletes the folder and then fails because the target path isn't there.

What am I doing wrong?

To add to this, because I have SourceTree installed (uses system git, not embedded), I let it do the update on the repository, and it works there.

Answer (score 0):

So, as usual, being too clever by half bites me in the arse again.

You may have noticed that in the above I'm using a git config shortcut for the host which allows me to refer to bb instead of bitbucket.internal.etc in the URL.

The submodules had the full servername in the repository path, so git couldn't find the right key to use, so it failed when trying to authenticate my session.

I added a duplicate config entry and provided the full server name as the nickname and voila, fixed.